# SQL Server: Get latest purchase data for all item/store groups

Tags: sql-server

I need to get information on the latest sale of each product in each store for a report I'm building.

I can get the information for a single row by running a query such as

```
select top 1 
    Purchases.ArticleID, Document.StoreID, Purchases.Cost, Document.Date 
from 
    Purchases 
join 
    Document on Purchases.DocumentID = Document.DocumentID 
where 
    ArticleID = 'xxxx' and StoreID=####
order by 
    Document.Date
```

But doing that would mean running over a hundred thousand individual queries which is a disaster.

Also, the query is actually more complex because tax information is stored in many other tables so the actual query is a mess of CASE-WHEN arithmetic and joins with at least 4 other tables.

Each purchases is recorded on the Purchases table with a unique identifier: `DocumentID`. The `Document` table holds the date of each transaction (not just purchases) and links to other tables I need.

I thought of using a subquery to limit the pool of DocumentIDs so the query would only run for DocumentID's which corresponded to the latest purchases of each item in each store:

```
where Purchases.DocumentID in 
      (select max(Purchases.DocumentID) as DocumentID
       from Purchases 
       join Document on Purchases.DocumentID = Document.DocumentID
       group by StoreID, ArticleID)
```

But - while the subquery alone returns only one DocumentID for each storeID and each articleID (7 in total), I tested it for just one ArticleID and the main query returns 22 rows.

Worse, I discovered that a single DocumentID can have more than one line in the Purchases table (I didn't make it - I think they do this for promotions and other stuff; like "Buy 2 get 1 free"'s).

Basically, what I need is a way to tell the query to use data from only one row of the purchases table per item-store grouping.

Is a subquery the way to go and I should focus on finding out where the extra rows are coming from or is there a better way?

The actual query is 16 lines long and in Spanish but I'll post it if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
with MyValues as
(
    select P.ArticleID
        , D.StoreID
        , P.Cost
        , D.Date as DocDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by Document.StoreID, Purchases.Cost order by D.Date) as RowNum
    from Purchases P
    join Document D on P.DocumentID = D.DocumentID 
)
select ArticleID
    , StoreID
    , Cost
    , DocDate
from MyValues
where RowNum = 1
```

Comment: It returns only 3 rows (instead of the 7 it should) and two rows are for the same store (with different costs and DocDates)

Comment: @ConnorU my proposed solution is a shot in the dark. If you can provide some details we can make this happen. A slight modification to the above query should work for you. I just don't know what you are trying to do or what your tables and data are like. If you can post a sqlfiddle it would be very helpful.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem - I decided to use a join instead of an "in" because there were other variables to consider and the join managed to solve the issue for me. Thanks for the offer though!